# How to do a loop of regressions?

Tags: matlab, loops, regression

I have the following code for a single regression:

```
results = fitlm(Rm,R(:,1))
```

As I am trying the market model, I'm regressing the market return on the company return. So far this works for 1 share. How can I loop this for all companies in my dataset?
R is a 324:60 matrix and Rm is a 324:1 matrix.

edit:

It worked with that:

```
for i=1:40
    stats(i) = regstats(R(:,i),Rm);
end
```

How can I extract specific output variables from the stats struct?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Note that you swapped the arguments of `fitlm` between the first and second code segment. In the for loop, you also use [linear indexing](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) of `R`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: so, I tried this now:
for i = 1:60
results = fitlm(Rm,R(:,i));
end
but this doesn't work..
I want to get 40 different betas, t values, std, means, etc. but instead it only gives 1 beta as an output which means i didn't do the loop correctly. Does that make my question better?

Comment: First I want to regress Rm on the first column of R, then regress Rm on the second column of R, and so on.. and get all the coefficients, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you aren't storing your output for all 60 iterations. You want `results` to be a 60x1 cell array. Try:

```
results=cell(60,1);
for i=1:60
    results{i} = fitlm(Rm, R(:,i));
end
```

Comment: Doesnt work either. I get this error message: "The following error occurred converting from LinearModel to double:
Conversion to double from LinearModel is not possible."

Comment: I think it doesn't work, because the output of fitlm gives different vectors and matrices of different dimensions as an output. (R squared, residuals, coefficients, t values, p values, etc.) Is there no other way? Or can I code it in a way, so that it extracts beta values from the output into the results table?

Comment: Sorry i didn't realize what the output type was for `fitlm`. See my edit (to make `results` a cell array).

Comment: Now it worked. Do you know how i can extract specific variables out of results into a normal table? so that i can sort and filter the data?

Comment: Yeah, what properties do you want to compare/ filter?